# Qprocess wait for finish befor next start

Tags: python, pyside6

I want commit several folder with the svn command using the qprocess and show the user the output. But my problem is qprocess start already the next process befor it finished at the output is mixed in the window.

I tried already watiForFinished() but then the GUI is frozen. Sombody can help me?

```
import os, sys
import subprocess
import time
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QDialog, QMessageBox, QProgressBar, QPlainTextEdit, 
QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from app.ui.pages.commit import Ui_Dialog


class Commit_All(QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, work_path='', qss=''):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
    
        self.work_path = work_path
        self.qss = qss
    
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setStyleSheet(self.qss) 
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(QtGui.QPixmap(':icon.ico')))
        self.connectSignalsSlots()   
        self.commit_plain.setReadOnly(True) 
        self.finish_btn.setEnabled(False) 
        self.commit_plain.appendPlainText('Starting Commit\n')

        self.svn_commit()   

    def connectSignalsSlots(self):
        self.finish_btn.clicked.connect(self.close)

    def svn_commit(self):
        for wc in os.listdir(self.work_path):
            wc = os.path.join(self.work_path, wc)
            self.finish_btn.setEnabled(False)
            process = QtCore.QProcess()
            process.start("svn", ['st', wc])
            process.waitForFinished(-1)
            output = bytes(process.readAll()).decode("latin1")
            process = None
            if output == '':
                self.message(f'Project {os.path.basename(wc)} have no new Data!\n')
                self.finish_btn.setEnabled(True)
                continue
            for status in output.splitlines():
                match status[:1]:
                    case '!':
                        self.remove(status[8:])
                        continue
                    case 'A':
                        continue
                    case '?':
                        self.add(status[8:])
                        continue
                    case 'D':
                        continue
                    case 'M':
                        continue
                    case _:
                        continue
            msg = f'--> auto commit Proj. {os.path.basename(wc)}'
            self.commit(wc, msg)
            continue
        return

    def add(self, item):
        process = QtCore.QProcess()
        process.start("svn", ['add', f"""{item}""", '--force'])
        process.waitForFinished(-1)           

    def remove(self, item):
        process = QtCore.QProcess()
        process.start("svn", ['rm', f"""{item}"""])
        process.waitForFinished(-1)

    def commit(self, item, msg):
        process = QtCore.QProcess()
        process.started.connect(lambda: self.finish_btn.setEnabled(False))
        process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(lambda: self.handle_stdout(process))
        process.readyReadStandardError.connect(lambda: self.handle_stderr(process))
        process.finished.connect(lambda: self.process_finished(item))
        process.start("svn", ['ci', f"""{item}""", '-m', msg])

    def message(self, s):
        self.commit_plain.appendPlainText(s)
    
    def handle_stderr(self, process):
        data = process.readAllStandardError()
        stderr = bytes(data).decode("latin1")
        self.message(stderr)

    def handle_stdout(self, process):
        data = process.readAllStandardOutput()
        stdout = bytes(data).decode("latin1")
        stdout = stdout.rstrip('\r\n')
        self.message(stdout)

    def process_finished(self, item): 
        self.finish_btn.setEnabled(True)       
        self.commit_plain.appendPlainText(f'\nAll Data succesfully uploaded from Project {os.path.basename(item)}!\n')
```

Comment: You were already on the right track by using `process.finished` in `commit`. Use that to "queue" commands: as soon as the previous process has finished successfully, launch the next.

Comment: Do have an example how to implement "queue"?

Comment: Just use a `list` of commands, use `pop(0)` to get the first item and remove from the list, run it, and go on until there's no command left in the list.

Comment: Sorry for late replay. But i got it. Thanks for the help.